# Partial template specialization with second template type

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Its simplified version of my real problem. Why in the first case template specialization doesn't work?

If I swap first two functions then it will work.

Strange, but it works with msvc 19...

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename M>
void write_impl(T &result, M m) {
    for (const auto &i : result) {
        write_impl(i, m);
    }
}

template<typename M>
void write_impl(const std::string &result, M m) {
    std::cout << result;
}

template<typename T>
void write_impl_1(T &result) {
    for (const auto &i : result) {
        write_impl_1(i);
    }
}

template<>
void write_impl_1(const std::string &result) {
    std::cout << result;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> a{"42", "43", "44"};
    write_impl(a, 42); // compile time error
    write_impl_1(a); // works fine
}
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/T1G7M95z8)

Comment: The first case isn't template specialization; it's function overloading (but the first one need to know the signature of the second one to works correctly).

Comment: How can I achieve this behavior then?

Comment: swap the first two ? Why is that not the solution?

Comment: Which behavior do you want to achieve, exactly?

Comment: Template specialization with second(common) template argument

Comment: You can't with a simple function. But overloading works well, as you can see. If you really (but why?) want partial specialization, you can pass through a class/struct and a member function inside it.

Comment: Well, as I said, its simplified example, in real one these two specializations call each other

Comment: Maybe you can declare the first one, declare and define the second and define the first?

Comment: you can specialize a type with an `operator()`

Comment: @max66 wow, I declared all my functions in my real example and it works fine, thanks! Is there a point to switch to struct version? Or declarations are fine?

Comment: If works with a prior declaration, I think it's the best solution. Take only in count that isn't a funtion specialization but you have two different (and overloaded) template functions. My answer is just to show how to get a sort of function partial specialization mediated by a `struct` but, as you can see, loose type deduction.

Comment: Relevant c++17 (draft): §17.5.6 2 "A function template can be overloaded with other function templates and with non-template functions"; §17.7.3 "An explicit specialization [...] can be declared by a declaration introduced by `template<>`". See also §17.8.3 *Overload resolution* and §17.5.6.2 *Partial ordering of function templates* (for info on resolving which template function a specialization applies to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first case isn't a case of template specialization; it's function overloading.

Doesn't works because the first function call the second one that isn't declared. Switching the order, as you can see, works because the first (now second) know the declaration (and the definition too) of the second (now first).

You can't have template partial specialization for functions in C++; only full specialization.

You really need a sort of partial specialization, you can pass through a class/struct and a function inside it. You can partially specialize the struct/class.

For example

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename M>
struct foo
 {
   static void bar (T & result, M m)
    {
      for (const auto &i : result)
         foo<decltype(i), M>::bar(i, m);
    }
 };

template <typename M>
struct foo<std::string const &, M>
 {
   static void bar (std::string const & result, M)
    { std::cout << result; }
 };


int main()
 {
   std::vector<std::string> a{"42", "43", "44"};

   foo<decltype(a), int>::bar(a, 42);
 }
```

But, as you can see, isn't really handy.

Obviously, if you don't need a partial-specialization-for-function emulation, and you are comfortable with different and overloaded template function (given that are calling each other) you can declare the first, declare and define the second and define the first;

Something as

```
template <typename M>
void write_impl (std::string const &, M);

template<typename T, typename M>
void write_impl (T & result, M m)
 {
    for (const auto &i : result)
        write_impl(i, m);
 }

template <typename M>
void write_impl (std::string const & result, M m)
 { std::cout << result; }
```

Comment: You did not explain why the first case does not work though.

Comment: @Quimby - Good point. Answer modified to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

First, interesting find! Took me a moment.

Second, there is no such thing as partial specialization of function template.

Full specialization is OK, so the second implementation will chose the specialization.

The first case is an overload resolution between two template functions, the more specialized will be chosen. The compiler will first construct the overload list - with candidates for the call.

**Here's the thing,** `void write_impl(const std::string &result, M m)` **won't be considered because it is not defined yet!** The point of instantiation is directly after the template's definition. So, only the first template is in the overload set, it will match because a string is iterable and the instantiation will fail because `char` is not.

This will raise the same error about `foo`:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void bar(T &result) {
        foo();
}

void foo(){}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> a{"42", "43", "44"};
    bar(a);
}
```

Why does the second case work then? Because the compiler will "look ahead" to see all possible specializations. But they still have to be present at the point which would instantiate the specialization. So, my belief here is that the second case is undefined behaviour, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36999861). I am not very well versed in this dark corner of C++, I might be wrong here.

Why does MSCV work? Beats me, it is sometimes "special", maybe their point of instantiation is wrong, `foo` will incorrectly work too.